# Releasing channel in Go

Tags: go, channel

I have a TCP socket and 2 goroutines reading and writing to streams.
I am writing a goroutine that reads data from a channel. 
If the TCP connection is dropped then the read from the go routine will detect an error and stop.

But how do I release a channel that has a goroutine writing to?

Is there method like `chan.release()` or should I post a special packet that will tell the goroutine to end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`close(ch)` will close the channel.

If you are ranging over the channel then the for loop will exit when the channel is closed.
`val, ok := <-ch` allow you to check for closed channels. ok will be a boolean value with false if the ch is closed true if the ch is open.

Comment: Great! Thank You. I searched docs for `close` and `release` and there is no such there

Comment: Besides being in the above spec it is also in the standard documentation: http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/